How is "何をどうしているか" used in this sentence?
彼が知られてはいるが、何をどうしているかは見られるべきではないのだ。
The character is a police office. He wants to investigate but his friend is here. The friend knows he is a cop but the character as far I know doesn't want the friend to know their methods
"彼が知られてはいるが、何をどうしているかは見られるべきではないのだ。"
he's aware of us, but I shouldn't be seen" What does 何をどうしているか here mean?
I assume it's akin to "Our methods" but why is どう here used?

彼が知られて(は)いる means "He is known (to others)" rather than "He is aware (of someone)". Based on your description of the scene, isn't the correct sentence 彼に知られてはいる? Then the entire sentence would mean "Though (my existence is already) known to him, what I'm doing and how I'm doing it must not be seen by him".

Let's break down the core piece you bring up.

何【なに】をどうしているか
↓
[何]{what}　[を]{[OBJ]}　[どう]{how}　[している]{is doing}　[か]{[QUESTION]}
↓
how [someone] is doing what [they do]

Looking again at the second half of the sentence:

何【なに】をどうしているかは見られる【みられる】べきではないのだ。
↓
What [he] is doing and how [he] is doing it aren't things that should be seen.

Depending on context (who is speaking, and about whom), the inferred "he" here might need to be changed.
